# When trying to create a project in custom vision getting 'Access Denied'

Tags: azure

I got the following error while creating a [custom model using the python](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/Custom-Vision-Service/python-tutorial) and is getting the below error.

So why is the access denied?

Is it because of the API-key or something else?

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "train_cm.py", line 12, in
project = trainer.create_project("PneumoniaNormal")
File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\azure\cognitiveservices\vision\customvision\training\training_api.py", line 1537, in create_project
raise HttpOperationError(self._deserialize, response)
msrest.exceptions.HttpOperationError: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Access Denied'
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you've shared, it does seem like you're not using the necessary Training and Prediction Keys.

I followed the steps in the link you provided, and used garbage values for the training and prediction keys, and got the same results you did.

```
PS C:\Users\Documents\pyTest> python test.py
Creating project...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    project = trainer.create_project("My Project")
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\azure\cognitiveservices\vision\customvision\training\training_api.py", line 1537, in create_project
    raise HttpOperationError(self._deserialize, response)
msrest.exceptions.HttpOperationError: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Access Denied'
```

Using real Key Values from [customvision.ai](https://customvision.ai/) I was able to successfully create the project.

You should go to [customvision.ai](https://customvision.ai/), sign up, and click on the gear on the right hand side of the nav bar, in order to access your Keys.

Comment: So we can say that its a key problem?

Comment: @Abhishek
Yes you need to change these lines: https://imgur.com/c3bh93C

You get the values by logging in to customvision.ai and grabbing the keys highlighted here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/Custom-Vision-Service/media/python-tutorial/training-prediction-keys.png 

Accept the answer if you've found it helpful!